# Custom exponents for Lennard Jones in LAMMPS

Tags: simulation, molecular-dynamics, lammps

I am trying to run an MD simulation using this generalized version of Lennard Jones.

$$
U(r) = \left(\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^A -\frac{A}{B}\left( \frac{r_0}{r} \right)^B 
$$

However, I do not know how to implement this potential in Lammps.

I have been going through the manual and, as far as I cal tell, this potential isn't in there. All you can choose between is 9-6 or 12-6 for the exponents.

Hopefully, one can get around the problem without extending any c++ classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lennard-Jones potential is a special case of the [Mie potential](http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/Mie_potential), which is [available in LAMMPS](https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/pair_mie.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use pair_table to represent any pairwise potential in the form of a table